# Drawing a line over a scrollable image Problem!

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

In my iPhone App, I want to display two components:

- A scrollable image in one of the Views. I do this with `UIScrollableView` with `UIImageView` inside it.
- A line should be drawn in the view over a part of the image. I do this by using a subclass of `UIView` and drawing a line inside the `drawRect()` method.

The problem is if I put the Line View **over** the Image View, then the image won't be scrollable since it will not receive the user's touch events.

On the other hand, if I put the Line View **behind** the Image View, then the line won't be visible to the user.

Any idea how can I achieve both?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Put the Line View behind the Image View, then set the imageview as opaque.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing! but it is drawing the line behind the image!